# Multi Curl vs file_get_html from SIMPLEHTMLDOM optimization? slow loading page

Tags: optimization, dom, curl, web-scraping

I've been learning how to scrape pages using curl multi and simplehtmldom. I originally used regexp to get certain items until I discovered simplehtmldom which took off a whole lot of weight on my coding. PHEW! Anyways, my page loads pretty slow and I'm going to be scraping from multiple pages. I'm scraping from 3 right now and its taking approx. 5 sec to load, maybe a little longer. I was wondering what the best way to optimize my webpage? I am using curl to get a few pages as well as file_get_html from simplehtmldom. Should I just stick with simplehtmldom all the way?

Thanks in advance for your responses!

Comment: are you dynamically building a webpage, by scraping? this is at least what I make of your question. in this case, you should definitely to the scraping beforehand...

Comment: I figured it out that I can use curl mutli, and now use file_get_html. Thanks for responding though! but for those who want to know, I passed in each array element into a str_get_html(), I got another question answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5363600/problem-with-multi-curl-and-simplehtmldom-grabbing-only-header

Comment: Consider marking this question as resolved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution found by andrewliu:
"I figured it out that I can use curl mutli, and now use file_get_html. Thanks for responding though! but for those who want to know, I passed in each array element into a str_get_html(),"